# Ethernet not working after updating Windows 10 from 1703 to 1709

Tags: networking, internet, ethernet, windows-10-v1703, windows-10-v1709

PC with configuration:

- **Motherboard:** Asus X99-A/USB 3.1,
- **NIC:** `Intel Ethernet Connection (2) I218-V` (as per Device Manager)
- **OS:** Win10 N Student Edition.

With version 1703, everything was working flawlessly, but since I updated to 1709, I have no internet connection via the NIC.

---

I tried/checked:

- troubleshooting, which sometimes states that `ethernet has
  no valid IP configuration` and that the problem would be fixed now (green checkmark). The system then states that I am connected, the yellow exclamation mark on the network symbol in the taskbar disappears, but pops up again after a couple of seconds.
- troubleshooting again: `The standard gateway is not available`, and again, it states that it is fixed, but it isn't.
- disabling/enabling the NIC. I also tried to uninstall the driver of the NIC completely and re-install the latest version from Intel.
- updating the BIOS to the latest version.
- `ipconfig /relase`, `/flushdns` and `/renew`.
- that all services are enabled.
- pinging the router: Timeout.
- manually setting a valid IPv4-configuration in adapter settings.
- rebooting into safe mode.
- uninstalling VPN (Akamai NetSession Client)
- disabling Avast A/V completely
- the following commands in an elevated Command Prompt:

  - `netsh winsock reset catalog`
  - `netsh int ip reset reset.log`
  - `netsh advfirewall reset`
  - `ipconfig /flushdns`
  - `ipconfig /registerdns`
  - `route /f`

---

An old WiFi-stick did work yesterday, which initially **worked fine**. However, when I tried it again today, my system does not recognise it any more - I don't think this has to do with my original problem, though.

The router itself seems to be working fine - other devices have no problem connecting to it. Rebooting it didn't change anything.

I hope I didn't forget anything I already tried and maybe someone here has a solution?

Comment: try older NIC drivers

Answer (score 0):

#### I have no Internet connection via LAN

Try completely reinitialising all network states.

Run the following commands in an elevated `cmd` shell:

- Reset WINSOCK entries to installation defaults:

  `netsh winsock reset catalog`
- Reset TCP/IP stack to installation defaults:

  `netsh int ip reset reset.log`
- Reset Firewall to installation defaults:

  `netsh advfirewall reset`
- Flush DNS resolver cache:

  `ipconfig /flushdns`
- Renew DNS client registration and refresh DHCP leases:

  `ipconfig /registerdns`
- Flush routing table (reboot required):

  `route /f`

Comment: Thank you for your fast reply. I tried it, but unfortunately it didn't help.